# Play a list of MP3 on Google Home assistant

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I’m trying to build an intent to play a list of mp3 using “media response”. As I read in Action on Google documentation, the MediaResponse can include a list of media objects, I tested it but it doesn’t work. Here is my code:

```
       if(!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO')) {
          conv.ask('Sorry, this device does not support audio playback.');
        }
        else{
          var mo_list = [
            new MediaObject({
                name: 'Radio one',
                url: 'my_mp3_url_1.mp3',
                description: 'A funky Jazz tune'
            }), 
            new MediaObject({
                name: 'Radio two',
                url: 'my_mp3_url_2.mp3',
                description: 'A funky Jazz tune'
            })
          ];
          conv.ask( mo_list );
          conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Radio two']));
        }
```

What's wrong? If I use only one MediaObject instead of a list (i.g. conv.ask(mo_list[0]) ) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is designed to take a list (probably due to an earlier design or to accommodate multiple formats or features in the future), you should only pass one item in this list.

When the audio completes, you'll get a `actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS` intent if you're using the Action SDK or a Dialogflow Intent will be triggered with the `actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS` event. You can then respond with another MediaObject.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also did the test you are talking about (handling MEDIA_STATUS) but I want to start the next mp3 immediately (without Google Home saying words) and my code doesn’t work. It seems that is mandatory to insert a SimpleResponse (where Google Home says something) in addition to a MediaObject, so I can’t get the desired service (only mp3 playback without interruption). How can I solve? thanks

Comment: You should be able to have this SimpleResponse just be SSML, possibly with an empty audio.

Comment: As you suggested I tested it with a SSML with only an empty audio and it works on Google Home, but not on Android. To make it work on Android I had to put at least one character inside the tag <audio> e.g.<audio src="https_audio_link">test</audio>. In this way the word ‘test’ is not pronounced (but it is displayed on a phone screen) and I can get the required effect. Just to evaluate all the possible solutions, is there the possibility to call another intent when I get a MEDIA_STATUS intent? In this way I could separate the Intent that takes care of mp3 playback from MEDIA_STATUS. Thanks

Comment: You can't trigger an Intent that has a phrase attached to it, but you can have the two Intent Handlers call the same function in your fulfillment. (Plenty of other answers on SO that discuss.)